# How to create dll of cpp file?

Tags: java, c++, header-files, .lib

I know it's a very common scenario. I need to call two methods from my `java` code written in following `cpp` files:

```
//test.cpp
#include <somelib.h>
#include <test.h>
method1 ("hello" , "test", "result1");
method2 ("result1", "test_Case", "result2");
```

And the definitions of above methods are written in `somelib.lib` lib file. Here i am pasting the content of  `header` file related to `somelib.lib`.

```
//somelib.h
#define _SOME_LIB_H

void method1 (string a, string b, string c);
void method2 (string c, string e, string h);
```

I can't paste the content of `.lib` file because i didn't found any `.exe` to read it.

How should i create the `dll` so that i can access the above methods by calling it.

Comment: That depends on the compiler; you're also limiting yourself to the Win platform with DLL.  Do you specifically want a DLL or just the ability to call this code from Java?

Comment: No, I just want to call this code from java. I wrote about dll because i read it somewhere that we can call dll file from JNI. Can we call the java code without using JNI?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip17.html

Comment: Not yet, but looking into it. Actually i have never worked on this kind of issue. Would you please tell me whether can i call the lib content from javatip or not?

Comment: You can, it's just a matter of going through the process.  Most languages have some level of inter-operability, especially with C/C++ code.